# How to debug the string handling in my C++ program?

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem where whenever I run this code and put a space in studentName input it the program skips the next question and then ends.

This is what it looks like when I have a space in the student's name:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV6po.png

And this is what its supposed to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vGCe.png

And this is my code:

```
    string className;
    int classTime;
    string studentName;
    cout<< setw(50);
    cout << "Enter the students name: ";
    cin >> studentName;
    cout << "Enter first class name: ";
    cin >> className;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------
    ----------" << endl;
    cout << "|" << studentName << "|Monday |Tuesday|Wensday  |Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "|   9:00-10:00 |       |       |         |        |      |        |      |" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "|   10:00-11:00|       |       |         |        |      |        |      |" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "|   11:00-12:00|       |       |" << className << "|        |      |        |      |" << endl;
```

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  This is a perfect example for using a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to execute each statement, one at a time, and watch the values of variables.

Comment: Please edit your post with the *text of the input and output*, not images.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Sounds like the beginning of a Tony The Pony post :D

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `std::getline` to read in names with spaces.

The `cin` will finish string input when it encounters a space.

Comment: thanks a ton that fixed it!

Comment: If the answer was helpful, click on the checkmark.